# Regex returns escaped match in .NET - why?

Tags: c#, .net, regex, escaping

As you can see in the screenshort, *capture* captures the right value **Boton \"Reservar\"**, but that property doesn't seem to be available. *Value* returns that value but escaped, that's not what I need. Is this the normal behavior with .NET? It's usually the case that *Value* shows the same value as the object string, but this time it's escaped.

Also, as you can see in the Immediate Window, *capture.ToString()* and even *group* shows the value escaped.

Worse yet, *Value* is wrapped in quotes, which is not what the regex is supposed to match.

I already tried casting *capture* to *Group* and calling *capture.Captures* again to see if the real match is hidden in deeper groups but it isn't.

Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The string *in memory* is correct - it's just its representation in the immediate / watch / locals window which is escaped. I don't know why the people from Visual Studio decided to do that, but one possible explanation is that you can copy that string as is and paste in your code:

```
var match = "Botón \\\"Reservar\\\"";
```

And it will have the actual value of the capture. If you click on the magnifying glass next to the value of the "Value" property you'll see the string without the escaping.

Comment: You're right. And if I pass Value to Console.WriteLine it returns the string as I need it. Is there a method like WriteLine that returns string instead of void? Regex.Unescape didn't do it.

Comment: If you simply assign the value of the capture to a variable, you'll get the correct value: var captureString = capture.Value;

Comment: I wish that was the case but it's escaped.

Comment: Ok, I found the issue, some unexpected replaces in our code base were modifying the end result of the string. I got rid of those and now I can use the string as .NET gives it to me, escaped.